# I am getting a drink from refrigerator

Tags: vocabulary

I am getting a drink from refrigerator.

I take a drink out from refrigerator.

Which is more accurates? Can I just simply say I take out the drink?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stacexchange.com/) may be of interest.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked at ELL.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your refreshment is provided by [this gentleman](http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/playoffs/2010/news/story?id=6091766), you should add the definitive article **the**.

> I am getting a drink from *the* refrigerator.

or

> I am taking a drink out of *the* refrigerator.

You could use out from the refrigerator, but that doesn't sound quite right. Unless you mean, I am taking a drink out from (under) [William "Refrigerator" Perry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Perry_%28American_football%29).

Comment: In prototypic homes, there is only one refrigerator, so it is **the** refrigerator; like _the kitchen sink, the living room, the master bedroom,_ etc.